# How to use text type as primary key in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django but the ORM doesn't give a way to have a text primary key.I would like to have a primary such as `00RTTIN223`.Is there any other way to bypass that limite?

Comment: On the contrary, it's quite possible but ill advised. In fact regardless of weather you use django or not, the modern approach is to use integer primary keys as much as possible.

Comment: @e4c5 would you like to cite a reference for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a snippet from django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

>>> fruit = Fruit.objects.create(name='Apple')
>>> fruit.name = 'Pear'
>>> fruit.save()
>>> Fruit.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
['Apple', 'Pear']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CharField with unique=True and primary_key=True

Comment: no need for `unique=True` when `primary_key=True`.
[Django: Does "primary_key=True" also mean "unique"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58139240/9134517)

Answer (score 1):

[django documents about primary_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#primary-key)

```
class Product(models.Model):
    pid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: You have a typo in the snippet True=True

Comment: Fixed, Thank you.