# Django: Does "primary_key=True" also mean "unique"?

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hello i am testing Django authentication and nesting user data. I created a simple `MyProfil` model for my users. I wanted to test making a custom `id` and set the `primary_key=True` as `id = models.UUIDField`.

> models.py

```
 class MyProfil(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    aboutme = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    city = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

---

so far everything works in my favor but i have a question, that i could not answer myself even after reading the django doc.

> **Question**

Does `primary_key=True` on my `id` Field also mean `unique` or do i have to declare it?

Comment: yes, if you defined a primary key you are telling that is an unique identifier for each row in your database, a primary key should be that

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes**. Since a primary key means a value that can uniquely identify an object. In [the documentation on the **`primary_key`** parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#primary-key), we see:

> **`Field.primary_key`**
>
> If `True`, this field is the primary key for the model.
>
> If you don’t specify `primary_key=True` for any field in your model,
>   Django will automatically add an `AutoField` to hold the primary key,
>   so you don’t need to set `primary_key=True` on any of your fields
>   unless you want to override the default primary-key behavior. For
>   more, see Automatic primary key fields.
>
> **`primary_key=True` implies `null=False` and `unique=True`**. Only one primary key is allowed on an object.

Comment: Awesome answer... always helpful.