# How to add prefix value in model for two columns...?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add a Prefix(CLI, CID) into the two columns in one table but its working for me only the Primary Key but other field is not generating the CID00001 like this....
this is my model.py

```
class Prefix(models.Model):
cdClientID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=200)
cdClientNumber = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=200)

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('cdClientID', 'cdClientNumber'),)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.cdClientID:
        prefix = 'ATT{}'.format('')
        prev_instances = self.__class__.objects.filter(cdClientID__contains=prefix)
        if prev_instances.exists():
            last_instance_id = prev_instances.last().cdClientID[-4:]
            self.cdClientID = prefix + '{0:08d}'.format(int(last_instance_id) + 1)
        else:
            self.cdClientID = prefix + '{0:08d}'.format(1)
    super(Prefix, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

here its genrating the only clientID its PK and how can i generate the clientnumber also CLN00001 with autoIncrement

tnx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this is going to work in actual web servers, but it seems to work in Django shell. Take your code:

```
class Prefix(models.Model):
    cdClientID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
```

The reason why I removed `editable=False` is because you need to do something like the following:

```py
>>> str = 'CLN' + 1
>>> p = Prefix.objects.create(cdClientID=str)
```

You need to parse number formats later on to get the leading zeros, but this is briefly how you do this.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43756776)

Comment: No no the cdClientID is generating the CLN000001 but i want create like that only

Comment: cdClientNumber also i need to generate like CLD000001 how to do this one... this will be done in one table..

Comment: So that's what I covered in the second block. You can't directly generate a string with characters and numbers. You must do it separately and then add them together. The format thing is just filling out the zeros in front of `000001`. By the way, seeing as there aren't ways to generate this as primary key directly, every time to create this object, you need to pass in its id as an argument.

Comment: if i enter the other fields like name there it should be  look like
| cdClientID | cdClientNumber | name |
| CID00001  | CLN0000001     | mahesh |

when i enter name field the other remaining will be generate CID00001 and CLN00001 and it should be auto Increment

Comment: Yes, you can auto increment it, but I don't think you can do it directly in the fields. Perhaps call a concatenate function somewhere where you create your objects.